# Button wrap_content not working in LinearLayout

Tags: android, user-interface, button, layout, android-linearlayout

So I've been trying to make a project that creates a new Button(with numerical text by order) whenever I press that LayoutInflate Button.
(I wrote a question and a problem on the bottom of this post)

What I have made so far is these:

1.MainActivity java file

->java file that inflates button 
in buttonlayout.xml to Linearlayout in mission.xml file

```
package com.example.a13_1_mission1;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btn_inflation;
LinearLayout container;
static int num=1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mission1);

    btn_inflation= (Button)findViewById(R.id.inflation);
    container = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);

    btn_inflation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            Button inflatedButton = 
            (Button)inflater.inflate(R.layout.buttonlayout,null);
            inflatedButton.setText("버튼"+(num++));
            container.addView(inflatedButton);
        }
    });



  }

}
```

2.mission.xml

->file that offers a Linearlayout(that contains new Buttons) and the inflating Button UI.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/inflation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="#6999"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="LayoutInflate"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textSize="10sp" />




    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:background="#6999"
        android:orientation="vertical">


    </LinearLayout>
```

3.buttonlayout.xml

-->layout of Button to be inflatedenter image description here(textsize and stuff).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="10dp">
</Button>
```

PROBLEM & QUESTION: Although I set width and height in buttonlayout.xml to be wrap_content, new manufactured buttons is not correctly adjusted.
here's a photo of my situation to help understand :

[As you see in the photo, the left one is the objective and the right one is mine.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPzZN.png)

Comment: Make your linearlayout width to wrap_content .

Comment: And set  android:gravity="center" in your parent LinearLayout

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. I tried it but here's a few issue : 1.graybackground won't show up until I create the first button.   2.even though I created few buttons, the gray background only shows itself in the middle of layout.

Comment: please try my answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please update your xml with below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/inflation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="#6999"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="LayoutInflate"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/containermain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:background="#6999">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

MainActivity.java

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.buttonlayout,null);
((Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button)).setText("\"버튼\"+(num++)");
container.addView(view);
```

buttonlayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp">
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```